# python - append and remove function in looping

Tags: python, list

```
birds = ["turkey", "hawk", "chicken", "dove", "crow"]
bird = []
for animal in birds:
    if animal.startswith("c"):
        birds.remove(animal)
    else:
        bird.append(animal)
print (birds)
print (bird)
```

why the outcome of birds and bird is difference?!?!

Comment: What's your thoughts around it? Why dont you expect difference?

Comment: Short answer: You need `for animal in birds[:]:` Long answer: Read the docs...

Comment: Long answer: You're effecting the list that you're iterating over with remove(), birds[:] creates a copy of the list that isn't effected by remove(), so you don't skip `dove` in your loop. You should use list comprehension.

Comment: that's because in this way one item removed from that array and all of them won't be iterated.